# What is the difference between an array with shape (N,1) and one with shape (N)? And how to convert between the two?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Python newbie here coming from a MATLAB background.

I have a 1 column array and I want to move that column into the first column of a 3 column array. With a MATLAB background this is what I would do:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.zeros([150,3]) #three column array

B = np.ones([150,1]) #one column array which needs to replace the first column of A

#MATLAB-style solution:

A[:,0] = B
```

However this does not work because the "shape" of A is (150,3) and the "shape" of B is (150,1). And apparently the command A[:,0] results in a "shape" of (150).

Now, what is the difference between (150,1) and (150)? Aren't they the same thing: a column vector? And why isn't Python "smart enough" to figure out that I want to put the column vector, B, into the first column of A?

**Is there an easy way to convert a 1-column vector with shape (N,1) to a 1-column vector with shape (N)?**

I am new to Python and this seems like a really silly thing that MATLAB does much better...

Comment: In MATLAB matrices are always 2d (or higher).  From a numpy perspective that's an artificial construct.  Why not 1d (vectors) or even 0d?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [squeeze](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html) method to eliminate the dimensions of size  1.

```
A[:,0] = B.squeeze()
```

Or just create B one-dimensional to begin with:

```
B = np.ones([150])
```

The fact that NumPy maintains a distinction between a 1D array and 2D array with one of dimensions being 1 is reasonable, especially when one begins working with n-dimensional arrays.

To answer the question in the title: there is an evident structural difference between an array of shape `(3,)` such as

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

and  an array of shape `(3, 1)` such as

```
[[1], [2], [3]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Several things are different.  In `numpy` arrays may be 0d or 1d or higher.  In MATLAB 2d is the smallest (and at one time the only dimensions).  MATLAB readily expands dimensions the end because it is `Fortran ordered`.  `numpy`, is by default `c ordered`, and most readily expands dimensions at the front.

```
In [1]: A = np.zeros([5,3])
In [2]: A[:,0].shape   
Out[2]: (5,)
```

Simple indexing reduces a dimension, regardless whether it's `A[0,:]` or `A[:,0]`.  Contrast that with happens to a 3d MATLAB matrix, `A(1,:,:)` v `A(:,:,1)`.

`numpy` does `broadcasting`, adjusting dimensions during operations like sum and assignment.  One basic rule is that dimensions may be automatically expanded toward the start if needed:

```
In [3]: A[:,0] = np.ones(5)
In [4]: A[:,0] = np.ones([1,5])
In [5]: A[:,0] = np.ones([5,1])
...
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (5,1) into shape (5)
```

It can change `(5,)` LHS to (1,5), but can't change it to (5,1).

Another broadcasting example, `+`:

```
In [6]: A[:,0] + np.ones(5);
In [7]: A[:,0] + np.ones([1,5]);
In [8]: A[:,0] + np.ones([5,1]);
```

Now the (5,) works with (5,1), but that's because it becomes (1,5), which together with (5,1) produces (5,5) - an outer product broadcasting:

```
In [9]: (A[:,0] + np.ones([5,1])).shape
Out[9]: (5, 5)
```

---

In Octave

```
>> x = ones(2,3,4);
>> size(x(1,:,:))
ans =
   1   3   4
>> size(x(:,:,1))
ans =
   2   3
>> size(x(:,1,1) )
ans =
   2   1
>> size(x(1,1,:) )
ans =
   1   1   4
```

---

To do the assignment that you want you adjust either side

Index in a way that preserves the number of dimensions:

```
In [11]: A[:,[0]].shape    
Out[11]: (5, 1)
In [12]: A[:,[0]] = np.ones([5,1])
```

transpose the (5,1) to (1,5):

```
In [13]: A[:,0] = np.ones([5,1]).T
```

flatten/ravel the (5,1) to (5,):

```
In [14]: A[:,0] = np.ones([5,1]).flat
In [15]: A[:,0] = np.ones([5,1])[:,0]
```

`squeeze`, `ravel` also work.

Some quick tests in Octave indicate that it is more forgiving when it comes to dimensions mismatch.  But the `numpy` prioritizes consistency.  Once the broadcasting rules are understood, the behavior makes sense.