# Numpy broadcasting 2d-1d problems

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have three numpy arrays:

```
X1.shape = (500,)

X2.shape = (5000,)

Y.shape = (5000,500)
```

I can run `X - X2` without a problem.
But `Y - X1` results in:

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5000,500) (5000,)

If I change to `Y - X1[:,None]` this seems to work while `Y - X2[:,None]` gives the error:

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5000,500) (500,1)

Please clarify!

Comment: 1 can match with 500 or 5000.  500 does not match 5000. [None,:] is automatic if needed.

Comment: So I should see it as "column" vectors? the broadcasting? But why then is the [:,None] working in the first, but not the last example?

Comment: (m,n)-(m,1), (m,n)-(1,n) are ok. (m,n)-(n,1) is not. (1,n)-(m,1)->(m,n) also works

Comment: I explain this in more detail in https://stackoverflow.com/a/40268064/901925 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/47277623/901925

Comment: Great! Thannks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to multiply 2 numpy array with different dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40267131/how-to-multiply-2-numpy-array-with-different-dimensions)